# textbox and button does not recognize touch when added as a subview of a label

Tags: iphone

I am using this to add a text box and a button as a subview of label pLabel.

[pLabel addSubview:pTextbox];
[pLabel addSubview:pButton];
[self.view addSubview:pLabel];

When I run the application, I see both of them, but the text box or the  button no longer responses to my touch. Could you please let me know how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

This might not be an appropriate use of labels though.  You might want to consider subclassing from something other than `UILabel`.